# Include Customers note field in PDF invoice

Tags: php, pdf-generation, prestashop, invoices

I'm asking if it's possible to add customers additional information (I think it's note column at customers table) to my PDF invoice and if so then how I'm newbie and have to learn a lot of things. I checked this [post](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/67723-how-to-edit-pdf-invoice-content-in-prestashop-131/) but it's not clear at all. Can any help me?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us the PHP code snippet that performs the actual PDF generation of, e.g., the user address. According to your [PrestaShop link](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/67723-how-to-edit-pdf-invoice-content-in-prestashop-131/), it may be found somewhere in the classes/PDF.php file.

Comment: @Thomas sorry for the delay I was out. Here is the code you ask me before: http://pastebin.com/iHQLCGGw

Comment: It seems to be the wrong file. I don't know PrestaShop, but could you try to find a file that generates the PDF invoice and references user details such as first name, last name, address, etc.? I think there could be the right place to add your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible to add customers additional information. It is simple, find your invoice what you want modify and match on function call for the invoice in file `class` > `pdf.php`.

ex: `multipleOrderSlips` function. 
The function `multipleOrderSlips` have call `order` object.
You should modify `order` to add customer information, you can add `JOIN` table.